# "In the case of" or "In case of"

Tags: grammar, verbs, articles, questions

I am wondering whether "in the case of" is a correct expression.
I know "in case of" can be used, for example "In case of an emergency" but when would be appropriate to use "in the case of" as long as it is correct.

Thank you.

Comment: In "general" contexts, such as [*In case of emergency, break glass*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22In+case+of+emergency+break+glass%22&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CC4Q7AlqFQoTCOLLur-JiMcCFUsSLAodJAAHBg&biw=1202&bih=843) we don't normally bother with articles (including ***an***). But in **the** case of **a** highly specific reference (such as this one), we usually include both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that, in cases like this, you use a search facility such as

[Google ngram: in the case of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20case%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20case%20of%3B%2Cc0)

That way you will find plenty of examples if the idiom exists.

Click on the links at the bottom of that page to see how the expression is used.

**My example**

*Jane is doing well at school but, in the case of John, I think we need to consider finding a private tutor.*

This is equivalent to

*Jane is doing well at school but, in John's case, I think we need to consider finding a private tutor.*

Answer (score 1):

I am possibly wrong but I would say that 'in case of fire we install fire alarms' but 'in the case of a fire, we use them'.
I suggest the lack of an article is an error.